# VBscript & cmd full command what is missing?

Tags: vbscript, cmd

```
Dim objShell 
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /k tzutil /l "
```

when running the first script it worked fine but when running the second script full command it does not so what is missing?

```
Dim objShell 
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /k tzutil /s "Israel Standard Time""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra double quotes and try again:

```
objShell.Run "cmd /k tzutil /s Israel Standard Time"
```

Or, if you want to pass the time zone inside double quotes, you can try this:

```
objShell.Run "cmd /k tzutil /s ""Israel Standard Time"""
```

Or, you can just write,

```
objShell.Run "tzutil /s Israel Standard Time"
```

All these will let you change the current time zone to Israel's Time Zone.

Comment: Yes the 2nd one did the job

Comment: No problem. Happy to help